# i want to build regular expression to extract substring from string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this: `"date created:12 march 1996phone:33444567Location:california steet 5"`

`date created`, `phone` and `location` are fixed but their value is changing. I want to extract them from string and want to display them separate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) to split the string at the keywords:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(date created|phone|location):/', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it...

```
$str = 'date created:12 march 1996phone:33444567Location:california steet 5';

preg_match_all('/^date created:(?<date_created>.*?)phone:(?<phone>.*?)Location:(?<location>.*?)$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(67) "date created:12 march 1996phone:33444567Location:california steet 5"
  }
  ["date_created"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "12 march 1996"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "12 march 1996"
  }
  ["phone"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "33444567"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "33444567"
  }
  ["location"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "california steet 5"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "california steet 5"
  }
}
```

This uses named capturing groups so you can access the data with...

```
// Example only, of course this is as bad as using `extract()`
$date_created = $matches['date_created'];
$location = $matches['location'];
$phone = $matches['phone'];
```

[See it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/LjGPQ)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('~date created:(.*)phone:(.*)Location:(.*)~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Just curious, what special meaning do ~ symbols have in PHP regular expressions?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes They are being used as the regex delimiter. Any matching pairs can be used (as long as they don't clash with existing syntax).

Comment: Ok. I didn't knew you had to put both ' single quotes *and* regex delimiters. Is that so you can specify regex options (like this `'~blah~i'`? Or some other reason?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes Just because `/` can clash with a few things such as directory separator and closing HTML tags (I bet someone links to bobince's answer). :)

Comment: ~ means nothing! you just have to provide a single char which marks the pattern to start and to end. You can choose whatever char you want. "/" is also a common char for this.

Comment: Yes, I understand why you can pick any pair of delimiters. What caused me confusion was the use of two pairs of delimiters (one for the string, another for the regex). A quick google search confirmed my suspicions of allowing the specification of regex options. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: In PHP regular expressions are not part of the language syntax like in Perl, ECMAScript, Ruby, etc. They are only possible using a string that holds the regular expression (similar to Java, Python, etc.). And since PHP uses the PCRE library, they adopted the syntax with `/` delimiters separating the regular expression and modifiers (although they could have used a class instead). And as the `/` is quite often also part of the regular expression, they added the feature to use almost any printable non-alphanumeric ASCII character as well.